# String.format usage with HTML without Conversion problem

Tags: java, html, format

I need to add some content to an HTML string in Java. This HTML is used in an email, which is sent by the Java servlet (by using *jakarta.mail*).

#### HMTL

In a file:

```
<button style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
    <a href=%s style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%">Link can be clicked</a>
</button>
```

Which is read by `String mailBodyBase = Files.readString("some/path/to/my.html")`.

#### Value and formatting code

```
String URL = "\"https://some.url/at/%s\"";
String urlForUser = String.format(URL, "set236sdgh235JH"); // the argument is actually retrieved from DB
return String.format(mailBodyBase, urlForUser); // Exception occures here
```

#### Expected Result

```
<button style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
    <a href="https://some.url/at/set236sdgh235JH" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%">Link can be clicked</a>
</button>
```

I am doing this instead of a much more simple `.concat()` because it is possible that we want to add more values to the HTML at some point.

#### Exception

But am getting an `UnknownFormatConversionException`:

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ';'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2732) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2718) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897) ~[?:?]
```

The same works pretty well with:

```
<html style="padding: 30px 0 0 30px; font-size: 16px">
    <h2 style="background-color: #0077bd; color: #eff; padding: 10px 5px;">App Name</h2>
    %1$s
</html>
```

And put content into this frame with `String body = String.format [...];`.

### Solution

##### Mask the *%* in the CSS with another *%*.

#### Old:

I have read [the docs for *String.format*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) and a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples), but I cannot see **the problem from there. It might be related to the quotes (*"*) in the HTML.**

Do I need to use another tool or *String.format* a different way?

Comment: @user16320675 The `%` should be a placeholder. The url for the href should be placed exactly there: `<a href=%s style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%">`. There is no `%;` in the format string / file.

Comment: @user16320675 Oh f*ck, yes, you are so right. Sorry for not being able to use my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduces the issue.

The issue in the following line:

```
<a href=%s style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%">Link can be 
clicked</a>
```

When using String.format() function we use %s or %d as placeholders to place the values.

in your case the **< a >** tag is having style attribute with ; and % which is causing the error.
You can fix it by replacing the style attribute with class name.

in your css file create style class as following:

```
.styleClassName{
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%
}
```

and change the  style attribute as follow:

```
<a href=%s class='styleClassName'>Link can be 
clicked</a>
```

Please do comment if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It might work, but I will just mask the *%* in `width: 100%;` etc with another *%*.